# Loop - Accept multiple times input from a single textbox name in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

(this might get confusing) i have 2 textboxes which would accept color and amount from a user ten times:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <i> color </i><input type="text" name="text[]">
  <i> color amount </i> <input type="number" name="num[]">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Now what i want to happen is that instead of declaring ten text boxes for color and amount i would just want to loop it so that after the first color and amount had been sent it would again ask for 9 times without displaying 10 textboxes for each name. Is there a way in php to loop it?

Thanks.
Regars,
Russel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@russel
try this. This one is in pure php.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $_SESSION['count']=0;

    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
  <i> color </i><input type="text" name="text">
  <i> color amount </i> <input type="number" name="num">
  <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo $_POST['text'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_POST['num'];
        echo "<br>";
        $count=$_SESSION['count']++;
        if($count==9)
        {
            echo "you have received 10 values";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "press ok to get again";
            ?>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="ok" value="ok">
            </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['ok']))
            {    
            header("Refresh:0");
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Anandhu, thank you very much. I'll try this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Ajax. You can store a counter variable in JS and when it reaches 10 you just disable the form or show a message to the user.

[jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

If Ajax is not an option you always can have the counter in your PHP file. I would sugget storing it in a session. Then when counter reaches 10 you just dont echo the form or something.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['counter'] = (!$_SESSION['counter']) ? 0 : $_SESSION['counter'];
if($_POST['submit']) {
   $_SESSION['counter']++;
}
```

EDITED: a basic idea (not tested yet) I would use button.click to avoid any kind of form submision

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <i> color </i><input type="text" name="text[]">
    <i> color amount </i><input type="number" name="num[]">
    <input id="button" value="OK" type="button">
</form>

<script>    
    var formCounter = 0;    

    $("#button").click(function(e) {
        var url = ""; // Whatever
        alert("OK");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: '', // Your data here
            success: function(data) {
                // Do you need to show confirmation?
                formCounter++;
                if(formCounter > 9){
                    // Disable/Hide form here
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: **@Jose thank you very much for your answer man. Appreciate it. I'll try to use the session code 'cause we must do it in pure php. Thank you.**

Comment: Great. Give it a try and come back if you still encounter problems. I'll be happy to help. If you think this is a good answer mark it so it can help others.